# little help on asp - response write

Tags: asp-classic

I set a variable :

```
Dim adoRecordset
```

and set it as:

```
Set adoRecordSet = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

adoRecordset.Open mSQL , adoConnection , adOpenForwardOnly
```

and I use it into show my data from database

eg.  1. `<td align="left"><%=adoRecordset("loc")%></td>`

and I would like add a asp code "if" & "else"

but this :   2. `Response.Write "<td adoRecordset(loc)></td>"`

doesn't work.

How can I make asp code 2. work as 1.  ?

Answer (score 3):

My asp classic is rusty, but I think you are looking for something like:

```
<% 
If adoRecordset("loc") <> "" Then
   Response.Write(adoRecordset("loc"))
End If
%>
```

Or with a local var to cache the result:

```
<% 
Dim someLoc
Set someLoc = adoRecordset("loc")
If someLoc <> "" Then
   Response.Write("<td>" & someLoc & "</td>")
End If
%>
```

If you've got large amounts of conditional `Html` output, then you can switch out of server code again, like so:

```
<% If something or other Then %>
  Some Conditional Html Here
<% Else %>
  Else Html here
<% End If %>
```

`<%=` is shorthand to emit a value
whereas `<%` escapes to server side code.

Comment: seem like it work!  but how can i put the <td> into resposne write?

Comment: You can concatenate the `td`s around the output string in the `Response.Write`, or switch back to Html output.

Comment: Stuart  can i ask  how to change  : <td align="left"><input type="text" VALUE="0" name="Quantity" size="10"> </td>     to asp?

Comment: It seems the only likely variable is the default value. So in an Html block: `<td align="left"><input type="text" VALUE="<%= myVBVariableHere %>" name="Quantity" size="10"> </td>`.
`myVBVariableHere` can also be a recordset field, e.g. `adoRecordset("loc")` etc as well.

Comment: can i chnage it  like  :   mHTML = mHTML & "<input type=text name="test" style=text-align=left> "
or   
                Response.Write "<INPUT Type=Text Size=10 Name=Item Value="0">  ?

Comment: If it is just static HTML, then you can use `Response.write` or end the ASP code block i.e. `%>Some HTML here <%`. w.r.t. `mHTML += ` just be careful of the performance implications of building up a big string from many smaller strings (concatenation), e.g. in loops.

Comment: i rewrite it to  :  response.Write "<td align="left"><input type="text" VALUE="0" name="Quantity" size="10"></td>"     but it doesn't work ~

Comment: It's the quotes. Either double them up viz `"<td align=""left"">` or use single quotes `"<td align='left'>`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim adoRecordset
Set adoRecordSet = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

adoRecordset.Open mSQL , adoConnection , adOpenForwardOnly

if not adoRecordset.EOF then

    do while not adoRecordSet.EOF
        if adoRecordset("columnName") = "test value 1" then
            response.write("<td>" & adoRecordset("columnName") & "</td>")
        else
            response.write("<td>I want to do something else here</td>")
        end if

        adoRecordset.movenext
    loop
end if

adoRecordset.close
set adoRecordset = nothing
```